# How can we read a VCD disk into Ubuntu?

Tags: video, vlc, vcd

A friend of mine asked me to rescue some familiar videos he has into a CD-R disk.

But, the disk was written with Roxio VCD format (not the standard video disk format). So... When I try to read it into Ubuntu, there is no files menu, or any Table of Contents, and the system tells me: "There is no media".

Even so, I can see the videos with VLC Player because the videos are IN the disk!!!

But, I can not to copy or convert to any other format because no programs I have installed can recognize the video files.

Somebody told me that I can play it on an external DVD device and take the analog output signal to save it into the computer, which is correct, but... I wonder... Why I can not to play it... Directly!!!

What's wrong with this disk? ???

How can I play it, directly, into the PCMan Files Manager? ???

Is there some fix to this? ???

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

But your best bet, if you want to keep the file is to run in through Handbeske first and convert it to a standard format.

As to why, Roxio uses DRM which won't allow normal users to watch their, the users, property.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the Ubuntu-Restricted-Extras, and... Nothing!!!

Comment: I could not to install Handbeske, no Handbrake. There is some problem with their repositories (maybe they are out-of-date?).